# response stream and ask for saving pdf file

Tags: asp.net

in asp.net, after creating a reportDocument, I would like to save it as a pdf report without showing it. In other words, I would like to show a response that the user chooses to save it:

```
ReportDocument reportdoc = new ReportDocument();

reportdoc.Load(Server.MapPath("CrystalReporttest.rpt"));
reportdoc.ExportToHttpResponse(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Response, false, "test123.pdf");
```

So far, I have tried it like this and it shows the pdf report rather than ask for "save it".

It is a directly way to do so in asp.net?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking for the file to download to a client without a save dialog box? If so, this isn't possible for browser security reasons.

Comment: no, I would like to response to the pdf to save it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer,

it is like this:

reportdoc.ExportToHttpResponse(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Response, true, "test123.pdf");

Stupid me!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a [`Content-Disposition` header](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/260519).

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the converted PDF in memory or on the file system and transmit the file like a regular file download using TransmitFile.